# Accordion conditional open and close function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

I implemented a simple accordion menu for my mobile view with clickable images as menu headers.

I would like to have only one category open at a time, basically, a click on picture 2 should open the picture 2 accordion content body, but close all the other accordion content bodies. Right now I would need to click on the each picture again to close its body.

Hope that makes sense.

This is my code thus far:

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 103%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin: -5px;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion"><div class="bolimg">
    <img class="bg" src="/files/0.jpg">
  </div></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/1.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/2.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/3.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/4.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/5.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you considered using JQuery UI Accordion? http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: are you using jquery library...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little script i can come up with.

I added the next css class to control the state of the accordion and to avoid doing the css with js:

```
.accordion.active+div {
  display: block
}
```

The script validate two things

1. If there is one open al ready
2. If the one clicked is the same as the one that is opened

I hope this help, if you need anything else i'll be around

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
var open = null;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (open == this) {
      open.classList.toggle("active");
      open = null;
    } else {
      if (open != null) {
        open.classList.toggle("active");
      }
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      open = this;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 103%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin: -5px;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.accordion.active+div {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion"><div class="bolimg">
    
    <img class="bg" src="/files/0.jpg">
   
       
  </div></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/1.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/2.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/3.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/4.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion"><img class="bg" src="/files/5.jpg"></button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @FatTwin Happy to help

Comment: I realized one issue with it: If I click on img 2, it closes the body content of img 1, but scrolls down basically. I would like to click on img 2, but stay at img 2. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @FatTwin not really jajaja, can you maybe add your code. Or maybe you can do another question and tag me. The thing is this content is to small for an actuall scroll to happen

Comment: I'll just do another question, but it's the same code (just a long img/text where it says "Content body text")

Comment: @FatTwin okok, pliss tag me so i can help. I dont really know what could be the problem but i also cant really visualize the behaviour.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48775676/accordion-scroll-issue-scroll-to-top-of-active-accordion

Comment: I added the new question, I am not quite sure how to tag someone proper here. @.. doesn't do it on Chrome for me

Comment: Perfect, ill take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `jQuery` library, try to make use of

- **[`removeClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)**
- **[`addClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)**
- **[`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)**
- **[`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)**

> *<sub>Note: I have removed the images from your code and places just numbers for visuals</sub>*

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$(".accordion").on("click", function() {
  $(".panel").removeClass("show");
  $(this).addClass("active").siblings(".accordion").removeClass("active")
  $(this).next(".panel").addClass("show");
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 103%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin: -5px;
}

.bg {
  width: 100%;
}

.active,
.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.panel.show {
  display: block
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 0px;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">4</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">5</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">6</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Content body text</p>
</div>
```